# Why system Call inside container takes more execution time?

Tags: docker, kernel, system-calls

We are facing issue where system call taking more execution time inside the container as compared to with out container.

### Docker container setup :

```
BASE OS Container : Ubuntu Container image
CAPS ALLOW : sys_resource sys_nice sys_tty_config ipc_lock
```

### HOST OS:

```
RHEL 7.3
```

## Time taken outside container :

time ./a.out

for loop took 8.690000 seconds to execute

for loop took 9.170000 seconds to execute

```
real    0m9.188s
user    0m1.768s
sys     0m7.419s
```

## Time take inside container :

for loop took 64.123517 seconds to execute

for loop took 64.316575 seconds to execute

```
 real    1m4.503s
 user    0m1.449s
 sys     1m2.870s
```

We running following piece of code to check the execution time of a system call

```
 int main()
 {
     int key,share_id,num;
     char *data;
     int semid;
     int count= 0;
     struct sembuf sb={0,-1,0};
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    if(!fork())
    { //Child Porcess
          for (int i= 0 ;i < 50; i++){
             for (int idx =0; idx < 1000000 ; idx++){
                sb.sem_op=-1; //Lock
                semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);
                count++;
                sb.sem_op=1;//Unlock
                semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);
             }
          }
     }
     else
     {     //Parent Process
        for (int i= 0 ;i < 50; i++){
            for (int idx=0; idx < 1000000; idx++){
                sb.sem_op=-1; //Lock
                semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);
                count++;
                sb.sem_op=1;//Unlock
                semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);
             }
       }
     }
    t = clock() - t;

    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

    printf(" for loop took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem with my python app in flask... outside the container take 10 seconds, but when i run it in the container take 30 -35 seconds.